# How to create image with if conditions on flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, if-statement, widget, containers

There is a container with an image inside like this

```
Container(

              child: GestureDetector(
                onDoubleTap: () {
                  //print("double tap");
                  showAlertDialog(context);
                  call(url);
                },
                //child: Image.asset('resimler/primeLogo.png'),

                child: Image.memory(
                    image!,
                    fit: BoxFit.contain,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.3,
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3),
              ),
```

This container allows me to display an image within the page. However
I want this image to be displayed only when the x variable is greater than 100, otherwise it will not occur at all. To do this, I tried this.

```
if(x>100){
              return new Container(
                child: GestureDetector(
                onDoubleTap: () {
                  //print("double tap");
                  showAlertDialog(context);
                  call(url);
                },
                //child: Image.asset('resimler/primeLogo.png'),

                child: Image.memory(
                    image!,
                    fit: BoxFit.contain,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.3,
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3),
              ),

            )],
          }else{
              return null;
    }
```

How to i do that? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this (x>0) ? Widget() : Widget()  condition.

```
Container(

          child: GestureDetector(
            onDoubleTap: () {
              //print("double tap");
              showAlertDialog(context);
              call(url);
            },
            //child: Image.asset('resimler/primeLogo.png'),

            child: (x > 100) ? Image.memory(
                image!,
                fit: BoxFit.contain,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.3,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3),
          ) : Container(),
       ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Where you want to display the photo you will replace it with `x>100:'resimler/primeLogo.png'?null`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this widget inside column/stack, or something similar. You don't have to use `else` state.

Simply use  `if(x>100) Container()`. Also, you can use `Visibility` widget to handle this type of situation.

**Example**

```
Column(
        children: [
         if(x> 100) Container(),
```

When it's  on `child` use `Visbilty`

```
   Visibility(
            visible: x > 100,
            child: Image(image: image),
          ),
```

Also if you still want to use `else state`, follow this way:

- create a method inside state
- or use getter

```
  get getWIdget => {
        if (x > 100)
          Container()

        /// for empty space
        else
          SizedBox()
      };

  Widget getWidgetWithParameter(int x) {

    if(x>100) return Image(image: );
    else return SizedBox();
  }
```

Comment: In the else case, I want the image not to be invisible, but not to occur at all.

Comment: hope you will get while you running the code.

Answer (score 0):

The `build` method of a Stateless/Stateful widget always needs to return a `Widget`. If you do not want to display anything if x not greater than 100 then in `else` block just return an empty `SizedBox` or `Container`.